# Windows 7 has trouble installing software with Visual C++ 2005 & 2008

Tags: windows-7, installation, visual-c++

I have been reinstalling Windows 7 over and over again on an ASUS P5lD2 2Gb Ram 3Ghz P4 because it ultimately loses the contents of "Turn Windows Features On or Off" after I install software like Autocad 2010 & Microsoft Office 2007.  I get install errors like 1935 and 1704 on the way tried different fixes at different times (install software in different order to try and isolate problem too). Ultimately I force the software to install after much buggering and end up losing the contents of "TWFOOO"

Should I be installing some older items like .net framework 1.1, 2.0 and Visual Studio items like vcredist_x86.exe?

getting a bit lost because of compounded problems...

Comment: Do you have a specific question you are asking?  As it is worded right now your post sounds more like a rant and will likely get closed.

Comment: You are right. should not have been thinking out loud when writing my question.

Comment: Are you using 64- or 32-bit Windows 7? I had enough weird software issues with the 64-bit version that I switched back to 32-bit. It might be worth looking in to.

Answer (score 0):

The [advice](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931712) by Microsoft is basically to run as Administrator: `sfc /scannow`.

It's probably motivated by the idea that one of your installations is destroying system files. So my advice is to install only software that you're absolutely need and sure about.

And regarding .NET Framework, I would suggest to install only version 3.5 SP1. This installs all versions since 2.0, and it's unlikely that you'll need 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I found two resources:

1) [Enable the "Windows Modules Installer" service](http://www.vistax64.com/vista-general/66510-windows-features-have-disappeared.html#post333308)

2) [Use Microsoft Support solutions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931712). Either run the System File Checker (SFC.exe) tool with the `sfc /scannow` command (as already mentioned) or perform a system restore.

Comment: You might want to summarize the linked pages.